# Did Michael Flynn commit crimes other than perjury?

Tags: perjury

I understand that he pleaded guilty to perjury. On the things that he lied about, were any of them indictable offenses? Would he have been likely to be convicted?

Comment: Lying to a federal agent is not actually perjury (https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1001). You probably know that Martha Stewart and Bernie Madoff went to prison for this. It is often easier to prove than the underlying crime.

Comment: What specific "lies" are you asking about? Lying is not an indictable offense, so basically the question contains legally false presuppositions and can't answered at least in terms of the law.